# AngularJS ng-repeat not display my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

My ng-repeat does not display my data. But in `console.log` it displays normally. I am using laravel with backend. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="t in teste">
        <td>{{t.id}}</td>
        <td>{{t.total}}</td>
    </tr>    
</div>


<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("//localhost:8000/angular")
  .then(function(response) {        
      $scope.teste = response.data;
      console.log($scope.teste);



  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please translate to english

Comment: This question belongs to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This is an English site, please translate your question to English or post to the exchange for your language.

Comment: my ng-repeat does not display my data. But in console.log it displays normal

Comment: @DiegoMarcelo `<tr>` is part of the table, you need to wrap your code with `<table>` tag

Comment: thanks man !!! Now is correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code updated, I think that you only need to wrap tr tag in in table tag. Hope it helps...

**Also I put call to fake API for data because in your example is used localhost link**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then(function(response) {    
  setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
           $scope.teste = response.data;
        });
    }, 0);
     

  });
});
</script>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table >
  <tr style="text-align : left">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th colspan="2">Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="t in teste track by $index">
        <td>{{t.id}}</td>
        <td>{{t.title}}</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
       
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread was made some time ago, and so this is for the random person who stumbles into this on a google search. I made the mistake of not using `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat`, which is not used in the the latest version of Angular. I read the docs to figure this out: https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference